# Can I have two foreign key from one table to an other, in order to get two columns field?

Tags: sql, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two tables one Player and the other Result. Can I set two foreign key on Result, related to Player, so that I can change the value of an two players with the Result? I am working on Ruby web application where I will update the fields for each Player according to the results I am going to add that are related to a football game. For example, if the score is Player1 3 - 0 Player2, Player1 will get 3 points while the other 0, so basically from one result I will have to change two fields from the table Player. I will also have to add the GoalsScored and GoalsTaken by each player. Can I sort this thing out assigning for example two names in result, I will check the name in the Player table and then change the fields, using two foreign keys, or I need just to set my methods correctly?

Here are the tables:

```
Player
t.string :name
      t.integer :win
      t.integer :draw
      t.integer :lose
      t.integer :gs
      t.integer :gt
      t.integer :dr
      t.integer :points

Result
t.string :name1
      t.integer :goal1
      t.string :name2
      t.integer :goal2
      t.datetime :date
      t.references :player, null: false, foreign_key: true
```

Is it ok if I add two references to Result?

Comment: Whose names are `name1` and `name2`?

Comment: The names of the players. So the result is displayed as name1(player1) goal1 - goal2 name2 (player2)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. And sometimes that's a good idea, but not here. You want a join table instead. Here's why.

You need to use two different column names and tell Rails what table they reference.

```
Result
  t.string :name1
  t.integer :goal1
  t.string :name2
  t.integer :goal2
  t.datetime :date
  t.references :player1,
    null: false,
    foreign_key: { to_table: :players }
  t.references :player2,
    null: false,
    foreign_key: { to_table: :players }
```

And you'd need to make them explicit in your code.

```
class Result < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :player1, class_name: 'Player'
  belongs_to :player2, class_name: 'Player'
end
```

Tying them together in Player is a little tricker. The naive thing to do is this.

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :player1_results,
    class_name: 'Result',
    foreign_key: :player1_id
  has_many :player2_results,
    class_name: 'Result',
    foreign_key: :player2_id
end
```

What if you want all the Player's results? What if you want all the players of a Result? There's the problem. You need to make redundant queries or add extra clauses like `where player1_id = :player_id or player2_id = :player_id`. Similarly `name1`, `name2`, `goal1`, `goal2`.

---

Whenever you want to store more than one associated thing, you need a join table. Even if it's only two. It makes life much easier.

You have a result table, but a result of what? A match! Where's information about the match stored? In the result table. It should be its own table.

We have three tables. Players, Matches, and a table to store how a player did in a match (the result).

```
create_table :players do
  t.string :name, null: fase
  ...
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :matches do
  t.string :name, null: false
  t.datetime :date, null: false
  ...
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :results do
  t.references :player, foreign_key: true, null: false
  t.references :match, foreign_key: true, null: false
  t.integer :goals
end
```

Now with all three pieces, we can put them together. The Matches and Players are related *through* Results.

```
class Matches < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :results
  has_many :players, through: :results
end

class Players < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :results
  has_many :matches, through: :results
end

class Results < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :match
  belongs_to :player
end
```

Now if you want to find the players in your match...

```
players = match.players
```

This will perform the join on results for you.

If you must track who is player 1 and player 2, add that to the Result table with a unique constraint.

```
create_table :results do
  t.references :player, foreign_key: true, null: false
  t.references :match, foreign_key: true, null: false
  t.integer :goals, null: false, default: 0
  t.integer :player_number, null: false, default 1

  # Can't have two player 1s for the same match.
  # :player_number is deliberately first so this index also serves
  # to index player_number.
  t.index [:player_number, :match_id], unique: true
end
```

Then you can get player 1 like so:

```
player = match.players.find_by!(player_number: 1)
```

And you can add some convenience methods to the relationship.

```
class Matches < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :results
  has_many :players, through: :results do
    def player(num)
      match.players.find_by!(player_number: num)
    end
  end
end

player = match.players.player(1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, very well descriptive. So, if I want to change the fields according to the game result, for example to update the win of each player, should I define a method into the result, so it automatically updates the fields in the Player class? I am quite new to Ruby and still trying to figure out everything.

Comment: You could do that with a [callback](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html), but you'd probably want to do it on the Match because it knows both results and can figure out who won.

Comment: What should I put in Match? I still get very confused, I thought it was clear, but the more I read your answer the more it gets complicated to me. If I have 1 matchID for 2 Results which must have each player with each goal scored, what am I going to store in Match?

Comment: Which is the join table, match or result?

Comment: Result is the join table. It joins Matches with Players. Result stores anything about a particular Player and Match: goals, fouls, etc. Match stores things like the name of the match, when it was played, and where it was played. If you want to store the results of a match, you'd use `match.results.create!( player: player1, goals: 3, player_number: 1); match.results.create!( player: player2, goals: 0, player_number: 2);` This performs queries like `insert into results (player_id, goals, player_number) values (42, 3, 1); insert into results (player_id, goals, player_number) values (23, 0, 2)`.

Comment: @axis93 FWIW the way you structure data in SQL takes a lot of getting used to. Especially how it deals with lists, like a match with many players. It's unlike how most programming languages work. If you're familiar with set theory that might help. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins might help. It's worth it.

Comment: I have done joins and join table so I am a little bit familiar with it, the thing is that to me it just makes everything more complicated to structure it, just because I don't store the name of a match, as it doesn't have it, and it doesn't have the location either, although your suggestion is a sensible thing to do

Comment: . As I only need to store the goals and the player, the match will only have an ID and a date, while the rest will be foreign keys. My thought is: if a player has many matches, that have many results, for each match, there are 2 results or 1 (draw) shouldn't it be :
`class Players < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :results
  has_many :matches, through: :results
end `
I am just trying to see if my thoughts are correct or not, as I don't like blindly "copy-pasting" someone else's work, I hope you don't mind trying to help on this.

Comment: @axis93 Regardless of what you store, you still need something to represent a match. / You've written the same Player class as in the answer. / If it's a draw the Match still has two Results, one for each Player in the Match. / While this is more complicated (in that there are more parts) it makes queries easier. For example, consider how you'd find how many goals a player scored across all matches. With a join table: `player.results.sum(:goals)`. Without a join table: `Result.where( player1: player).sum(:goals1) + Results.where( player2: player ).sum(:goals2)`.

Comment: I apologise, I thought it was results through matches, which was the ReasonI was getting confused, now it makes perfect sense. Thank you very much for your help!!!